# How to encapsulate specific word in brackets?

Tags: python, regex

I am a newbie to Python and here is my problem. I have a set of words:

```
entities = ['blab', 'r1', 'zss']
```

I want to detect them and I want to encapsulate them in case there aren't

For Instance :

`this r1 is about zsse` **-->** `this [r1] is about [zsse]`

Again if there are already encapsulated I won't change anything , for instance, `[ blablab r1 blabala ]` would still be the same.

I have tried something but it doesn't work:

```
for s in sentences:
    for e in entities:
        if re.search(r"\[\[%s\]\]" % e, s):
            pass
        else:
            s=s.replace(e,'[['+e+']]')

        New_sentences.append(s)
```

Comment: You need to expand your regex to allow zero or more characters before and after the word. Which may be anything, except ...

Comment: Do you want words to be immediately enclosed with `[ ]` or there could be more word within those brackets. Secondly what about nested brackets like `[ad cd[ad]]ad` and you want to enclose `ad` ?

Comment: How does `zss` in your list relate to `zsse` in your example? Is that a typo, or do you really want to do a prefix match?

Comment: In your input sentences, will the `[` ever be nested? Will they ever be unbalanced?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it. Note that I use two different regular expressions:

- `(\[.*?])` identifies what regions are inside brackets already
- `'({})'.format('|'.join(entities))` matches any of the entities inside the non-bracketed regions.

```
import re

brackets = re.compile(r'(\[.*?])')
def rewrite(sentence, entities):
    sentence = brackets.split(sentence)
    entities = re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join(entities)))
    for i, phrase in enumerate(sentence):
        if not phrase.startswith('['):
            sentence[i] = entities.sub(r'[\1]', phrase)
    sentence = ''.join(sentence)
    return sentence

print rewrite('this r1 is about zsse', ['blab', 'r1', 'zss'])
print rewrite('[ blablab r1 blabala ]', ['blab', 'r1', 'zss'])
```

Result:

```
$ python x.py 
this [r1] is about [zss]e
[ blablab r1 blabala ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care if `entities` are substrings of words in sentences, then you don't have to use regular expressions.

```
sentences = ['this r1 is about zsse', '[blablab r1 blabala]']
entities = ['blab', 'r1', 'zss']
new_sentences = []

for sentence in sentences:
    if sentence.startswith('[') and sentence.endswith(']'):
        new_sentences.append(sentence)
        continue

    sentence = sentence.split(' ')

    for index, word in enumerate(sentence):
        for entity in entities:
            if entity in word:
                sentence[index] = '[{w}]'.format(w=word)

    new_sentences.append(' '.join(sentence))

print new_sentences
>>> ['this [r1] is about [zsse]', '[blablab r1 blabala]']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import re

entities = ['blab', 'r1', 'zss']
sentences = ['this r1 is about zsse', 'this [r1] is about [zss]e']
new_sentences = []

for s in sentences:
    for e in entities:
        if re.search(r"\[%s\]" % e, s):
            pass
        else:
            s=s.replace(e,'['+e+']')
    new_sentences.append(s)

print(new_sentences)
# >>> ['this [r1] is about [zss]e', 'this [r1] is about [zss]e']
```

<kbd>[**Demo on Ideone**](http://ideone.com/f7L4O6)</kbd>

The only problem with your code was `new_sentences.append(s)` was indented too far. `new_sentences` was being `.append`ed every time `entities` was looped through. Therefore, for each `sentence` there were 3 `new_sentences`.

You also seemed to have everything as `[[]]` or `\[\[\]\]` instead of `[]` or `\[\]`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
In [48]: eentities = ['blab', 'r1', 'zss']

In [49]: s = 'this r1 is about zsse'

In [50]: import re

In [52]: rs = re.compile('|'.join(eentities))

In [60]: sl = list()

for se in s.split():
    if(rs.match(se)):
        sl.append('[{0}]'.format(se))
    else:
        sl.append(se)

In [62]: sl
Out[62]: ['this', '[r1]', 'is', 'about', '[zsse]']

In [63]: ' '.join(sl)
Out[63]: 'this [r1] is about [zsse]'
```

Comment: OP claims that his/her solution doesn't work! And out of the solutions provided this one uses a single for loop than multiple loops.

Comment: Yes, so rather that just posting a big section of completely new code (without even explaining it), why not analyze their code, tell them what they did wrong and how to correct it.